# Null object upon get "Output" on Package instance

Tags: content-manager, sdl-tridion

I'm trying to run publish page. But during the debug I get null in assembly in the next section of code:

Item outputItem = package.GetByName(Package.OutputName);

What this may indicate ?

Screen template builder with failed page component:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That tells you that there's no `Output` yet available to be read. Can you share a screen grab of the Template Builder where your code runs? If you write some code that needs access to the `Output`, you need to make sure that such output has been added to the package by another TBB prior to your code.

Comment: Tridion itself will also expect an Output item in the package by the time your templating code is finished running

Comment: Thank you for answer. I attached  screen of my template builder to my question. Small note: I had a working assembly a couple of days ago (written and upload not by me). but I wanted to see the process of debugging and uploading the assembly on the SDL from beginning to end and updated the assembly on the SDL. Then I returned the assembly to the version that worked. But it doesn’t work now the way it worked before. And now I get an error null object in the previously working assembl. I have no idea why this is happening

Comment: While on Template Builder, can you click on the Default Page Finish Actions TBB to see what's in the package at that time? Again, I think no Output is being added to the package prior to your template accessing it. I would recommend the state of the package before each TBB gets executed to see what's available in the package.

Comment: @JaimeSantosAlcón, thanks a lot. It really was a problem with TBB that didn’t work properly and did not add "Output" package during operation.